# What is the index of the relations in VSTS / AzureDevOps REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In the Official [Documentation of AzureDevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#update_a_link), the JSON Body to update an attachment is the following:

```
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/relations/2/attributes/comment",
    "value": "Adding traceability to dependencies"
  }
]
```

Where is this number `2` (in `relations/2/`) coming from?

---

So far I have understood that it is starting with zero but I can't figure out how it matches with the attachments.

By updating the comments of the attachments, I have been able to understood which is which but I cannot understand the logic.

The information related to the 3 attachments in a test case below correspond to: this magic index /  the attachment name / the attachment id (incremented each time an attachment is created) / the attachment id appearing in the URL:

- attachment #0 === default_AA.png === 122 === 87042366-deda-4634-8284-8f06ed552323
- attachment #1 === default_MC.png === 124 === 5a931981-9db8-41ba-ae0a-ca0b42e6d3fb
- attachment #2 === default_BB.png === 123 === acbc0e56-47c0-473a-a664-359f53c34a99

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is the zero-based index of the relations. The relations include attachments but also links, that this is what might have confused you.

For example, with Python REST API, the code could be the following:

```py
def get_relation_idx(tc, attachment_id):
    """Return the index in relations corresponding to a the attachment id (or part of it)"""
    for idx, rel in enumerate(tc.relations):
        if rel.rel == "AttachedFile" and attachment_id in rel.url:
            return idx
    return None

attachment_id = "87042366"
tc = wit_client.get_work_item(12345, expand="Relations")
idx = get_relation_idx(tc, attachment_id)
print("Attachment {} has index {}".format(attachment_id, idx))
```